# How to remove a callback that was previously registered in Julia?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, cplex, julia, jump

I'm coding in Julia, how can I do the same as "Remove(Cplex.Callback)" function does in C++ ?

Answer (score 3):

Currently there is no support for removing a callback from a model in JuMP. Your options are:

1. Rebuild the model
2. Set a new callback that does nothing

The [Julia discourse forum](https://discourse.julialang.org/c/domain/opt/13) is another platform you can browse on questions related to JuMP.